# Scrape URL links with Python

Tags: python, xpath, href

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php'
driver.get(url)

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]')

driver.close()
```

I want to scrape all the URL links associated with the soccer games from this site:  https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php

I always scrape all the `<a>` elements where the soccer games are included. But how can I extract the URLs linked to these soccer games?

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting webelements with `find_elements_by_xpath` you need to get `href` from it

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php'
driver.get(url)

links = []
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "match/cotes-")]'):
    links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

print(links)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse  #Import required modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx=ssl.create_default_context()  #Check certificates, you can skip this for some 
                                   #websites 
ctx.check_hostname=False
ctx.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE

userInput=input("Enter URL: ")
url=userInput if len(userInput)!=0 else "https://www.coteur.com/cotes-foot.php"

html=urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags=soup("a")                       #Find all html "a" tags, and print
for tag in tags:                 #The "a" tag is used to create link
    print(tag.get("href", None))
```

This program prints all the links it found on the page

If you want soccer related links only, you can modify the last line to:

```
if 'soccer' in tag.get("href", None):
    print(tag.get("href", None))
```